# Getting correct scalebar using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I apparently have a problem with getting meaningful scalebar values referred to a shapefile in QGIS. I think I tried all solutions suggested in other discussions, but still I don't get it. I use QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa.
The shapefile was downloaded from a reliable source (DIVA-GIS.org), it is a typical
administrative areas polygon.

In case anyone wants to try it, here it is:

http://gadm.org/data/shp/CHN_adm.zip

When it was downloaded it came set with WGS84.
I set the Project settings to: on the fly projection enabled, Project CRS WGS84/UTM ZONE 33N.

I set the layer CRS to WGS84/UTM ZONE 33N.

Then I "zoomed to layer" extent and added the scalebar: it reads 10 meters. Whole China
seems to span east to west about 60 meters.

I also tried to "save as" the shapefile with WGS84/UTM ZONE 33N, got a new shapefile and the new shapefile behaves just the same.

There must be a mistake I am doing, but I can't find what.

Answer (score 7):

Don't change the layer CRS! By changing the CRS in layer properties, you are telling QGIS to assume a wrong CRS. Just enable on-the-fly that's all.